# clCreateSubBuffer not found oO

Tags: opencl

i can't seem to find clCreateSubBuffer in cl.h or cl.hpp (only error macro). it is mentioned in the specifications, any idea about this? or any other way to create a sub buffer?

all i can think of is recreating the buffers using an incremented pointer.

Comment: Related threads on official forum: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/572548/support-for-opencl-1-2-gtx-690-ubuntu || https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/486564/nvidia-39-s-opencl-1-1-and-clcreatesubbuffer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that clCreateSubBuffer is a OpenCL 1.1 function, maybe your using/looking into openCL 1.0 header files.

What platform are you btw using? (im pretty sure that NVIDIA supports until now "only" OpenCL 1.0)

Comment: yep ur right, i had to rethink my whole memory management because of this, thanks.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 with package `nvidia-352-dev`. `glinfo` says that it supports OpenCL 1.1, but there is still no `clCreateSubBuffer` on `cl.h` given by that package.